# Dont show hidden div when the select option is in default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a simple fiddle.

And I want to implement it in my work..

my issue is that if I reload the page and the selection is the default it should not show any content from my last choice.

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" name="food_type1" id="food_type1">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disable" value="0">SELECT</option>
    <option value="1">Fruits</option>
    <option value="2">Meat</option>
</select>

<div id="food1" style="display: none;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="food1[]" value="Mango">Mango <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="food1[]" value="strawberry">Strawberry
</div>

<div id="food2" style="display: none;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="food2[]" value="Beef">Beef <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="food2[]" value="Pork">Pork <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="food2[]" value="Chicken">Chicken
</div>
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/bk2ohogj/4/

Comment: Sorry but how you are detecting if selection is default? Default from what? server? And what you mean "last choice" .. before page reload?

Comment: reload and yes sir

Comment: ok if I understand right, you select an option and check some checkboxes and then you reload the page .. what you expect after that?

Comment: the fiddle you linked to is using localStorage to store the selection. don't use localStorage if you don't want to store the selection.

Comment: but if I remove that, the hidden div will not remain.

Comment: @daremachine - remain the selected option and display the hidden divs, which is already given. the problem when you refresh the page and when the selected option is default there shouldn't any content visible. sorry if wrong grammar

Comment: I tested the Fiddle and it doesn't work as expected, which is a persistent storage of options (at least how I would expect if it was going to be useful). When I refresh, it doesn't keep anything. The key "storage' in the first function is trying to store an array, but `localStorage` cannot store the array, it can only store strings. Therefore the first function should use `JSON.stringify` on said array before using `.setItem`. After seeing that, I decided it's not worth it.

Comment: please check this one. its the same https://www.freightcenter.com/quote in location type.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are pulling information from localStorage on load.

```
//Get list type
if (localStorage.getItem("list")) {
    showList(localStorage.getItem("list"));
}
```

And it gets saved locally whenever you show a list:

```
//Show list according to Dropdown
function showList(type) {
    var $food1 = $("#food1");
    var $food2 = $("#food2");
    localStorage.setItem("list", type);
    ....
```

It keeps pulling the last value from localStorage and showing the list on load.

Comment: yeah, but that why I like it.

Comment: But isn't that causing the `div`s to show when they shouldn't?  Because on load it shows the last list that was stored, even if nothing is selected in the drop down list.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it.  I suggest doing one or the other.  If you want to preserve state, change the drop down selection to match the div you are showing.  If you don't want to preserve state, remove this feature.  Not sure how you can have it both ways on this.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help, I will work hard on this.

Comment: No problem, thanks for teaching me about `window.localStorage`!